# Country dependent popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kentico

I'm looking to get a popup that will tell you to go to the US website if you're browsing on UK one in the US and vice versa.

Just trying to find the best way to get the users country, having an IP database isn't really an option as we're looking for something as lightweight as possible.

Would it be possible to use the Google Geolocations API to achieve this, or maybe the CMS (Kentico 7)?

Comment: You can get the region Info of the current place and and show other place(s) in the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geolocation seems to be THE future way to determine user location. This is included as part of start HTML 5 specification. Since this is new, it implementation is not guaranteed by all client. In such cases it would be advisable to fall to standard IP based location tracking.

IMO, using ip-location map db should be fine. Exposing API over db should be easy talk. Or you can use some free api lib over net.

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php - seem to provide free lookups.

Comment: For curiosity I tried the ipinfodb link in Chrome at work: 1. Chrome asked me if it could use my location information, 2. My work ISP is in Wales but I am currently sat in England. So it works down to UK level, but any further I could be looking at a Welsh language site.

Comment: Just reading through the Geolocations API now. Is there an easy to way to get, let's say just the country name? It seems to get latitude and longitude but not just a straight up country name?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to download Kentico API Reference for version 7 from the [DevNet portal](http://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/older-documentation)
where you can find the class: **GeoIPHelper** under namespace: **CMS.WebAnalytics**

and there is a method which you can use in this scenario:

> `CMS.WebAnalytics.GeoIPHelper.GetCountryByIp(String)`

where String parameter is IPv4 address. You can obtain the current IP address using standard .NET method Request.UserHostAddress().

Comment: Thank you, ended up using Kentico in the end and passing the IP to http://ipinfodb.com/ to get the country name.